# On finding the open the balls that do not intersect a circumference.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose I have a set $S = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2 + y^2 \neq 1\}$.

And I want to find balls that lie completely in S. A set of balls that lie completely in S are the balls centred at $(x,y)$ with radius $\epsilon = \left\vert \sqrt{x^2+y^2} - 1 \right\vert $.

How is this epsilon found? Could I have some extra steps?

Answer (score 1):

One statement you may want to prove is the following: if $B_{\epsilon}(x,y)$ is the open ball of radius $\epsilon$ around $(x,y)$, and $\epsilon<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, then
$$\{|z|:z\in B_{\epsilon}(x,y)\} = \left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-\epsilon,\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\epsilon\right) $$
where $|z|$ is the Euclidean norm of $z$. To show that the LHS is contained in the RHS, use the triangle inequality. To show the converse, you can explicitly construct points in the ball whose norm is arbitrarily close to $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-\epsilon$, and similarly for $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\epsilon$.

Once you have proven this, then it's just a matter of choosing an $\epsilon$ such that $1\not\in(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-\epsilon,\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\epsilon)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I see that $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \le | \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} + \epsilon | \le  | \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}| +| \epsilon | $, is this what you meant?. But I am a bit lost on the other arguments.

Comment: I mean something like this: let $w = (x,y)$. Let $z$ be in the ball of radius $\epsilon$ of $w$. We know $d(z,w)<\epsilon$, and we want to show $|z| = d(z,0)$ is bounded from below and above by what I wrote above. By the triangle inequality, we have $d(z,0) \le d(z,w) + d(w,o) < \epsilon + \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, which gets one of the bounds. The other one can be obtained by noticing that $d(w,0)\le d(w,z) + d(z,0)$.

Comment: In fact, to answer the main question, you don't have to prove that the RHS is contained in the LHS. Just proving that the LHS is contained in the RHS, and choosing an appropriate $\epsilon$, will be enough.

Comment: how would one choose the epsilon such that $1\not\in(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-\epsilon,\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\epsilon)$ ? sorry first time doing these things.

Comment: Replace $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ by actual numbers (e.g. $2$, $3$, $1/2$, etc.), and play around to see what you get. As an additional hint, you want to consider the cases when $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is greater than 1, and the cases when it is less.

Comment: If I choose $x= 1 / \sqrt{2}$ and $y = 1 / \sqrt{2}$ then $1 \in (1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)$ for every epsilon so this epsilon does not exist. This leads me to believe I have not understood the question.

Comment: Is $(1/\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2})\in S$?